# Hard disk not directly connected to motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

This is a silly question but now-a-days since hard disks are getting smaller. Why can't the motherboard manufacturers make a slot for hard disk. This will increase hard disk speed incredibly.

Comment: They already are.. Search for PCIe SSD. Still pretty expensive, but it's there.

Comment: Why would that make the hard drive any faster? The limiting factor is the magnetic medium.

Comment: One day an entire PC will be integrated into a single chip die.

Comment: Macbook Air's have the SSD modules integrated onto the motherboard....http://9to5mac.com/2011/07/21/new-macbook-air-opened-up-ssds-not-soldered-to-the-motherboard-still-user-replaceable/

Comment: As do the OLPC machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Welcome to 1985.](http://www.google.com/search?q=hard+disk+pci+card)

Comment: I wanted one of those so bad back in the day, glad I did not waste the $$

Comment: I think you mean one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardcard

Comment: Back in 1985, sure. But no one uses those anymore.